Laravel Breeze Auth (Web-Based) + Sanctum Auth as API auth?
I'm trying to create an Internal Project, which uses the Breeze Package for Authentication.
However, now I want to retrieve Data from an API, which should also be protected, so I thought to use Sanctum Auth.
However, the XSRF-Token isn't valid on API Requests, so I am curious if there is a simple way, to use Breeze Auth for our API Endpoints as well?

maybe by converting Breeze Auth into an API Token? -

What I have done so far:
I created the Basic Laravel Setup with Breeze and VueJS as Frontend (Vite)
Laravel Version : 11.x
Installed API manually, after creating the Project.
Tried to authenticate with the XRSF-Token, we get in the Frontend.
